# Windows' AllocationPreference - like setting in MacOS to test 32->64bit code?

Tags: macos, testing, 32bit-64bit

As has been mentioned in previous answers here, Windows OS has a Registry key to force memory allocations from Top-Down to help catch pointer truncation issues when moving from 32bit code -> 64bit.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\AllocationPreference

However I don't see anything similar in MacOS. I wrote a quick program to check, and it seems that in 64bit, all memory allocated need at least 33bits to represent their address.

I'm wondering if a 64bit MacOS X program will ever allocate memory in address space that can be represented in 32bits or less? If I compile & run the same program in 32bit it obviously uses addresses in the lower 32bit space.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    void * ptr = NULL;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            ptr = malloc(10);
            if ((UInt64)ptr > INT32_MAX)
                printf("Pointer = %p > 32 bits required!\n", ptr);
            else
                printf("Pointer = %p <= 32 bits ok\n", ptr);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Matt

Comment: In 64 bits, all addresses require 8 bytes (64 bits). How are you compiling? You should append `-arch=x86_64` to your compiler flags (supposing gcc or clang).

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling as 64bit app. 
But my question is if there's any guarantee that memory addresses will always be greater than xFFFFFFFF when running as 64 bit. Running my program above shows this is true.